# How do you use setTitleTextAttributes:forState in UIBarItem?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uibaritem

How do you use `setTitleTextAttributes:forState:` in `UIBarItem` in `iOS`?

How do you set the `NSDictionary`? Can't make it work and documentation isn't very clear about that.

**From the documentation:**

```
setTitleTextAttributes:forState:
```

**Sets the title’s text attributes for a given control state:**

```
- (void)setTitleTextAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes 
                      forState:(UIControlState)state
```

Parameters:

attributes: A dictionary containing key-value pairs for text attributes. You can specify the font, text color, text shadow color, and text shadow offset using the keys listed in NSString UIKit Additions Reference.

state: The control state for which you want to set the text attributes for the title.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Example code:

```
[[UIBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
[UIColor colorWithRed:220.0/255.0 green:104.0/255.0 blue:1.0/255.0 alpha:1.0], UITextAttributeTextColor, 
[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor, 
[NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 1)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset, 
[UIFont fontWithName:@"AmericanTypewriter" size:0.0], UITextAttributeFont, nil] 
forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: [NSValue](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsvalue_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has no valueWithUIOffset method. My program crashed at that point in your code.

Comment: See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/NSValue_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: UITextAttribute has been deprecated starting iOS 7, you should use the values of the class NSAttributedString instead, for example instead of UITextAttributeTextColor you should use NSForegroundColorAttributeName

Answer (score 43):

**Swift 5.0:**

```
// Bar title text color
let shadow = NSShadow()
shadow.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
shadow.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1)
let color : UIColor = UIColor(red: 220.0/255.0, green: 104.0/255.0, blue: 1.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
let titleFont : UIFont = UIFont(name: "AmericanTypewriter", size: 16.0)!

let attributes = [
    NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : color,
    NSAttributedString.Key.shadow : shadow,
    NSAttributedString.Key.font : titleFont
]
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .normal)

// Or you can use
UIBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .normal)
```

**Swift 4.0:**

```
// Bar title text color
let shadow = NSShadow()
shadow.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
shadow.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1)
let color : UIColor = UIColor(red: 220.0/255.0, green: 104.0/255.0, blue: 1.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
let titleFont : UIFont = UIFont(name: "AmericanTypewriter", size: 16.0)!

let attributes = [
        NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : color,
        NSAttributedStringKey.shadow : shadow,
        NSAttributedStringKey.font : titleFont
    ]

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: UIControlState.normal)
// Or you can use
UIBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: UIControlState.normal)
```

**Objective C code:**

```
NSShadow *shadow = [NSShadow new];
[shadow setShadowColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0]];
[shadow setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 1)];

NSDictionary *attributes = @{
                                NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor colorWithRed:220.0/255.0 green:104.0/255.0 blue:1.0/255.0 alpha:1.0],
                                NSShadowAttributeName: shadow,
                                NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"AmericanTypewriter" size:16.0]
                             };

[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState: UIControlStateNormal];

// Or you can use.

[[UIBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Swift 4 is actually the following: ```[NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: color]```

You should update your code.

Answer (score 7):

Here's phix23's code, just with an updated, and I think cleaner, syntax:

```
[[UIBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{
                      UITextAttributeTextColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:220.0/255.0 green:104.0/255.0 blue:1.0/255.0 alpha:1.0],
                UITextAttributeTextShadowColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0],
               UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset: [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 1)],
                           UITextAttributeFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"AmericanTypewriter" size:0.0]}
                                      forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.tabBarItem setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor whiteColor], nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:UITextAttributeTextColor, nil]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift5** set `UIBarItem` title color

```
let attributes = [
    NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.orange,
    NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
]
vc.tabBarItem.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .normal)
```