# Statusbar color like UINavigationController color

Tags: ios, statusbar

I tried to match the color in status bar to my navigation bar color

I added "View controller-based status bar appearance" with NO to Info.plist
And added

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

to AppDelegate.m didFinishLaunchingWithOptions but still not work

[image: Example status bar like NavigationBar color]

[image: My app]

Comment: Hey look I found the same - http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/

Comment: The status bar only has options to be Light (white) or Dark (black) content. If you made it the same color as your Navigation Bar, then you wouldn't be able to see it...

Comment: How about setting `titleTextAttributes` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810563/how-do-you-use-settitletextattributesforstate-in-uibaritem/25382956#25382956

Comment: Are you looking for `setBarTintColor:` of the appearance proxy of `UINavigationBar`? The status bar will adjust to the navigation bar on iOS7.

Comment: I don't use UINavigationBarController I added only Navigation Bar from storyboard to the view

Comment: You can make the self.view.backgroundColor =  navigationbar color and make the navigation bar non translucent

Comment: But is change the view to color and I want only to change the background status bar color

Comment: yes but it will give that look similar to the iOS7 image

Comment: Thanks! but I want only change the status bar background like HandBook app.But thanks for your help!